# Cannot show a specific data on Drop Down Angular Js

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a problem that seems to be my drop down doesn't show the data whenever I will choose the appropriate selection. There are two selections on the choices.

CSHTML

```
<ui-select ng-model="ctrl.requestType" theme="selectize" title="Choose type of requisition" style="min-width: 140px;">

  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select type of requisition">
    <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
  </ui-select-match>

  <ui-select-choices repeat="existingRequestType.name as existingRequestType in ctrl.existingRequestTypes | filter: $select.search">

    <span ng-bind-html="existingRequestType.name| highlight: $select.search"> - 
       </span>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Angular.JS format

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout, $interval) {
      vm.existingRequestTypes = [{
          name: 'Purchase'
        },
        {
          name: 'Lease'
        }
      ];
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite sure you forget to define `vm`:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout, $interval) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.existingRequestTypes = [{
      name: 'Purchase'
    },
    {
      name: 'Lease'
    }
  ];
}
```

**OR**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout, $interval) {
  $scope.existingRequestTypes = [{
      name: 'Purchase'
    },
    {
      name: 'Lease'
    }
  ];
}
```